# PHP MongoDB Update immutable field '_id' updates itself

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to update a document in MongoDB via PHP.

From what I know the syntax seems correct, but it throws this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoWriteConcernException' with message 'localhost:27017: After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('5451f5163690a91a198b4567') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('5451fba53690a9ae1a8b4567')'`

My code is the following:

```
$val = array(
    'poiName' => 'Testname',
    'loc' => array((1.2345455, 9.98774949),
    'poiCategory' => 9,
    'cruiseName'=> 'testcruise',
    'poiId' => 123455677898,
    'source' => 'Rotiation',
    'sourceId' => 987654321,
    'user' => 'testuser',
    'createdAt' => new MongoDate($createdAtDateTimestamp),
    'createdAtRotate' => new MongoDate()
);

$pois[] = $val;

foreach($pois as $val){
    try{
        $col->save($val);
    } catch(Exception $ex){
        unset($val['createdAtRotate']);
        $newData = array('$set' => $val);
        $col->update(array('sourceId' => $val['sourceId']), $newData, array('upsert' => true));
    }
}
```

I'm doing the update in the `catch` block because it runs there if there is already a document matching on the index. By the update I don't want to update the 'createdAtRoute' Value.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The `sourceId` has unique index?

Comment: no, i got the syntax wrong, i'm answering it as soon as possible

Comment: Your real code is under an namespace?